# slideUp not working on valid jQuery-Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've the following javascript/jquery-snippet:

```
var msg = (function() {
    var active = null;
    var toggleBox = function(parent) {
        if (active != null) {
            if (active.next().length) {
                active.slideUp("fast", function() {
                    active = active.next();
                    active.slideDown("fast");
                });
            } else hideBox();
        } else {
            parent.show();
            active = $(".myBox");
            active.slideDown("fast");
        }

    }
    var hideBox = function() {
        if (active != null) {
            active.slideUp("fast"); // doesn't work :(
            // hide parent, too... but it's not necessary here...
        }
    }
return {
    toggleBox : toggleBox,
    hideBox : hideBox
}
})();
```

and the following few html-tags:

```
<div onclick="msg.toggleBox($('#parent'))">Show</div>
    <div id="parent" style="display: none;">
        <div class="myBox" style="display: none;">
            Message 1
            <div onclick="msg.toggleBox($('#parent'))">Next</div>
            <div onclick="msg.hideBox()">Hide</div>
    </div>
    <div class="myBox" style="display: none;">
        Message 2
        <div onclick="msg.hideBox()">Hide</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Now... when I click on my "Show", the first box will be shown and I'm able to close/hide the box. By clicking "Next", the second box will be shown. The Problem is, that I'm unable to hide the second box. When I try to use `alert(active.html())` I always get the correct html-code of the active object. I can also call `hide()` and the second box will be hidden, but simply no `slideUp()`... why? I'm getting a valid jQuery-Object.

Comment: I have a feeling this might have something to do with slideUp and slideDown actually changing the DOM elements you're targetting?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
var msg = (function() {
    var active = null;
    var toggleBox = function(parent) {
        if (active != null) {
            if (active.next().length) {
                active.slideUp("fast", function() {
                    active = active.next();
                    active.slideDown("fast");
                });
            } else 
                hideBox();
        } else {
            parent.show();
            active = $(".myBox").first(); //minor tweak here, if there is no active item activate the first myBox
            active.slideDown("fast");
        }

    }
    var hideBox = function() {
        if (active != null) {
            active.slideUp("fast"); // doesn't work :(
            // hide parent, too... but it's not necessary here...
        }
    }
    return {
        toggleBox : toggleBox,
        hideBox : hideBox
    }
})();
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/FMLgN/1/)